# Winform DataGridView not refreshing after changing datasource programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that won't update its contents after programmatically setting it's datasource. I've verified that the new data is fine, and tried .Refresh, setting the datasource to nothing and a few other things to get it to redraw itself with the new data. I've spent hours trying every combination of events (even downgrading the DotNet framework to 3.5 to see if it was a bug in 4.5 framework) and tricks from other forums. Nothing works.

```
Public Sub GetNewOrders(Optional calledfrompopup As Boolean = False)
    Me.dgvOrders.DataSource = QBI.Order_DataICT.GetNewOrdersICT()
    If calledfrompopup Then
        ''100% certain that the datasource info has changed, yet datagridview just won't reflect the change!
        Me.pnlOrders.Refresh() 'does not work
        Me.dgvOrders.Refresh() 'does not work
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically, another form that was opened, calls "GetNewOrders" in its form.closing event, then closes. The calling form has the method above and checks to see if it needs to refresh the datagridview (a solution I thought would work, but, alas, it does not).
As you can see, I've tried refreshing the panel that the datagridview is in (as well as the form itself). Refresh does absolutely nothing and there is no redraw or rebind or anything I can find that will FORCE the datagridview to reload itself.
Stumped! Answers in either C# or VB.Net language are okay.

---

another version of the function showing other things I've tried

```
Public Sub GetNewOrders(Optional calledfrompopup As Boolean = False)
    Me.dgvOrders.DataSource = Nothing 'does not work
    Me.dgvOrders.DataMember = "" 'does not work
    Me.dgvOrders.DataSource = QBI.Order_DataICT.GetNewOrdersICT() '100% certain that the datasource info has changed, yet datagridview just won't reflect the change!

    If calledfrompopup Then
        Me.pnlOrders.Refresh() 'does not work
        Me.dgvOrders.Refresh() 'does not work
        Me.dgvOrders.Show() 'does not work
        Me.dgvOrders.Visible = False 'does not work
        Me.dgvOrders.Visible = True 'does not work
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Setting the DataSource to null, before setting to the new value should fix it.

Comment: First thing I tried. That has no effect.

Comment: I want to comment that the DataGridView only refreshes correctly if I put a button in and have the user click it. I tried a .PerformClick, which did nothing either (in fact, it doesn't even raise the click event of the button, go figure)

Comment: It gets crazier - the dgvOrders_DataSourceChanged event does, indeed, fire, yet the DGV is still not reloaded.

Comment: Me.dgvOrders.ResetBindings() 'does not work either. UGH!

Comment: Me.dgvOrders.Invalidate() ?

Comment: Try <dgv>.columns.clear after setting the datasource to Nothing. Add Application.Doevents before updating the datasource as another straw to grasp at. Please be more specific than "does not work" in posts. A common problem in this area is that existing columns are just added to existing columns.

Comment: Tried that too. No joy. The columns clear (the event is fired), but the dgv, once again, is not refreshed. In fact the DGV fires all the correct events when they are supposed to (even DataSourceChanged), yet never redraws.

Comment: What I see happening is that, while the events are fired, the datagridview, somehow is not updating itself. The AutoResizeColumns event, for example, fires, but the columns are not resized. Same goes for background color or any I've tried. I can step through w/the debugger and it hits the breakpoints at the events, but does not change. Very strange - I think it's because the calling form is holding things up somehow (the GetNewOrders function is called by the calling form at its .Disposed event). Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Success!! What I figured out was that all I have to do is use ShowDialog() instead of Show() when opening the child form, so that when it closes, I only need to check for DialogResult.Cancel, then call the function GetNewOrders from the parent as in:

```
   Dim frm2 As New frmSendToQuickbooksPopup
    frm2.CurrentOrder = Order
    frm2.lineitems = OrdLineItems
    frm2.payments = OrdPayments
    Dim diaResult As DialogResult = frm2.ShowDialog() 
    If diaResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        GetNewOrders()
    End If
```

To explain: frm2 is opened and when it is closed, the datagridview (which is on the parent form) now sees that it is closed and calls the method GetNewOrders().

Answer (score 0):

You are refreshing inside of an if statement:

```
If calledfrompopup Then
```

Make sure you are passing in true and that you are making it in there. Next, instead of refreshing just set the data source inside of that if statement:

```
If calledfrompopup Then
    //The use of "Me" here may not be necessary.
    Me.dgvOrders.DataSource = QBI.Order_DataICT.GetNewOrdersICT()
```

Comment: I'm definitely getting there (in debug). 
I just use Me. for intellisense (makes typing faster).

Comment: Looks like this is simply not doable - maybe because I'm calling the function from another form, even though the function works perfectly, the datagridview does not reload. The mind boggling thing is that it works ONLY when you click a button (that calls the EXACT same function). How is that even possible?

Comment: Yeah that is strange. It sounds like it may be a timing issue then. Your method may be getting called too early, to test this try setting it on a timer so it gets called a little later. That's the only reason I can think of that it is working when clicking on the button.

Comment: I'll keep experimenting with different things - looks like lots of people are having this same problem.

Comment: I tried a little delay - formClosed instead of formClosing - no joy 


   Private Sub frmSendToQuickbooksPopup_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        Dim frmCaller As New frmGetNewOrders
        frmCaller.GetNewOrders(True)
    End Sub

Comment: OK - I think I know what the problem may be. I noticed when stepping through the program that the calling form, even though it fired it's closed event, has not actually closed yet (it was still open in the taskbar while I was stepping through the GetNewOrders function on the other form) - meaning it still has the focus. This must somehow screw up the events in the form holding the datagridview (but not all the events - the DataSourceChanged event fires).

Comment: In the DataSourceChanged event try closing the other form there first and then calling your method to update the grid. I still think it's a timing issue of some sort. When you click the button and it's working the open form is probably closed at that time and you are forcing the focus back to your main form.

Comment: I think I'll try setting a flag on the DGV form from the other form and have a timer that checks every few seconds for that flag, if set, then the function is called and the flag is turned off. It's a hack, but the only way I can think of. Unfortunately, now I have to have a timer running all the time.

Comment: as a last ditch effort - I called the method in the form Disposed event, the calling form disappeared, but it still didn't work. The timer is the only way.

Comment: Instead you could set up an observable property that when changed would call your method.

Comment: yes - but it wouldn't know when to start looking for that property without some sort of interval check (timer)

Comment: Observable properties really work off of events (notifications) so it wouldn't need a timer, it would just fire off when changed. Or you could just create your own event and fire it off from inside of your form that closes in it's dispose. Just an idea :)

Comment: A dirty work-around may consist in a temporary change of the DatagridView width or a reset of any other display attribute such as BackColor.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change to the DataGridView width, background, resizing works in this case. I'm trying a few more things before calling it quits (and telling everyone they have to click a button to refresh the results).

Comment: One more thing you could try is instead of having a fixed grid on your form is just creating one programmatically, give it the data source and then attach it to the form each time the data changes.